# W10327250 dishwasher inlet valve interchangeable with W10327248

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher

Dishwasher inlet valve W10327250 I received W10327248 instead no harness plug connector can I use the one off the old part

Comment: Would send it back and get the right part, it is their mistake.  Any changes you make to it, ends the warranty.

Comment: Is the valve *exactly* identical to the old valve, with the *exact* same number of wires, in the *exact* same position and the *exact* same color? The model # difference may just mean "part with connector" vs. "part without connector". If identical I would probably roll the dice and snip off and use the old connector.

Comment: Thank you I did send it back right why hassle with it and take chances with something going wrong then I’d have another bad part thanks I was just so focused on fixing it now